# problems with returning a value java

Tags: java, return, mouselistener

I have this method that contains a MouseEvent. How do I return the idu variable?
it is like a method in a method or how to call it and I can't figure out how top return the idu variable.

```
public int getId() {   
    int idu;
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
            JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
            int row = target.getSelectedRow();
            Object record = data[row][0]; 
            idu = (Integer) record;                
        }   
    }
    });  
return idu;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you might have a fundamental misunderstanding of how asynchronous programming works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nearly all cases the 'listener' pattern involves registering listeners with methods that do not have return values. In general a return value from a listener is meaningless because it's being returned to caller that has no context about what to do with it.

It seems to me you have misunderstood a few things in the code you have posted:
1. it makes little sense to register a listener in a 'getter' method. The listener needs to be registered once, generally in the class's constructor
2. registering a listener doesn't do anything on its own: it just tells the handler to call your method when an event occurs (in this case clicking a mouse).
3. unless you are reusing the listener in several places (which you are not in this code fragement because it's an anonymous class) then you don't need to get the event source - you should already have it as a member field in the class.

So the answer in your case is that your JTable should be a member field of your class. Then the getId method need only return the selected row of the table. There is no need to register a mouse listener at all as the selected row is available in JTable without any additional work.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the following question:

When do expect to have the `idu` value ready for use - when the method `getId()` finished running, or when the user clicked the mouse button over the table?

What your code actually do is to register an event listener, kind of like setting an alarm or scheduling a task for later, and then going to sleep, or back to do whatever other task you need to do now.

The value of `idu` doesn't neccessarily exist when you exit the `getId()` method, because the code in the `mouseClicked()` method didn't neccessarily executed yet. It will only execute when the **event** actually happen.